# Python-Splitting the string in a column to multiple columns by Delimiter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Ola\n1 October at 20:55 ·\nFollowing his foot
 The above is the output of my text. I need to create 3 separate columns like Company,Date,Content and need to put Ola in company ,1 otcober in date, following his foot in content.
n124\n569 comments\n11 shares How to do this too. As I am new to this part. Can you help me solve this issue?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, you are expected to show your attempt first and show where you are encountering a problem, please go through [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and[How to create a minimum complete verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(["Ola\n1 October at 20:55 ·\nFollowing his foot"], columns="bcd")
df[["Company", "Date", "Content"]] = df.bcd.str.split("\n", expand=True)
```